# I do not get notified when the system adds a canned "possible duplicated" comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, notifications, global-inbox

This happened to me twice. Someone flags my question as duplicated and only when I visit the question I notice the comment. Before I had no proof, but today I have *evil laughter*.

This is the notifications:

> [image]

I count 4, remember this number.

> [image]

Lets see... umm... 1, 2, 3... 5! HA! So, there are 5 comments and one of them (the one that flagged the question as dupe) didn't get into my inbox. So, is this by design or I really should get notified?

**If** this is by-design, I disagree.

Note to self: I suspect other canned comments doesn't reach the OP, like the custom close reason.

Comment: **If** it's by design, I disagree with the design. Users should definitely see if someone thinks they posted a duplicate. Then they can follow the link, dispute if necessary, or self-delete if warranted.

Comment: Agree it's not a good behavior. I guess the code responsible to send notification is part of the comment submission, while auto generated comments skip that phase. I would call it "bug by design". ;-)

Comment: @GenericHolidayName And most importantly; get the answer they really really needed

Comment: This is absolutely a bug; I can't think of any good reason to "silently" post comments like this when the whole *point* is to provide additional information to the author.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is entirely my fault - in the closure code, I didn't use an existing API for adding comments, which bypassed notifications.

Fixed in next build, > rev 2013.12.12.1754.

Comment: Man, this bug was here since forever then?

Comment: Many moons, my good man.

Comment: @JarrodDixon you might want to check this one too http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222480/213575