# I do not get notified if a moderator closes my question as a duplicate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, notifications

I asked [a question in the meta of Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/614/how-can-i-write-several-answers-recommendations-for-a-single-question), it was closed as duplicate of other question by a moderator, but I wasn't informed about it. This is likely related [to this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210953/i-do-not-get-notified-when-the-system-adds-a-canned-possible-duplicated-commen) in which case I didn't get notified about the canned comment, just that in this case there isn't any comment since moderator vote is binding.

Going by Shog's comment in my other bug:

> This is absolutely a bug; I can't think of any good reason to "silently" post comments like this **when the *whole* point is to provide additional information to the author**

If I do not get notified about my question being a duplicate how will I check for answers to that question?

Comment: I don't see this as a bug.  You are never notified of closures.  You are onlt notified of comments, and the comment is not generated when a mod closes your post regardless of the type.  If you want to be notified, this would be a feature request (and is probably a duplicate)

Comment: @psubsee2003 [please read Shog's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210953/i-do-not-get-notified-when-the-system-adds-a-canned-possible-duplicated-commen#comment677634_210953)

Comment: That is not relevant.  Shog's comment is about not notifying you of a comment, not notifying you of a closure.  In the quoted example, the mod did not close the post.

Comment: @psubsee2003 then quoting my own question "how I'm going to check the answers in that question?" I didn't get notification, for me the question is either too difficult to get answered or has some other problem. Why shouldn't a mod closure about duplicates send me a notification when other closures does?

Comment: Don't take my comment the wrong way, I agree that you should be notified of closures (any closure whether it is a dup or not).  My point is it is not a bug.  In the post you reference, the you were not notified of **a comment** resulting from a possible duplicate close vote (or flag).  But when a mod unilaterally closes a post, the comment is never generated.

Comment: @psubsee2003 so you are saying that should be a feature request?

Comment: Yes but I am almost certain being notified of closures has been requested before.

Comment: Here's the feature request I was thinking of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed

Comment: @psubsee2003 that is tangentially related, since mine is very specific to something that OP is awfully interested of (like somewhere else answers to my question may already exist).

Comment: Oh, I wasn't thinking of that, sorry. Mind you, I think that [all closures should be notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed). I don't see why duplicates more so than the rest.

Comment: I love the meta-ness of the fact that this question itself was closed as a duplicate!

Comment: @randal'thor: To be even more meta: Your comment was the first thing notifying the OP of the closure.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft not really, the first close vote by  psubsee2003 generated automatic comment that notified the OP about the possible closure. (and the comment got auto deleted once the question was closed)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: But that’s again part of the problem of a lacking closure notice (which of course is another discussion). Anyway, technically, my statement was correct.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft closing as duplicate is different as it generates the automatic comment and that's why this question here got reopened.